# Differentiate between 1:1 Bot conversations

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I am in a 1:1 chat with my bot.
as part of a command, the bot responds with a card (say Card1) and a couple of action buttons. I persist the conversation id and activity id from the context.
I issue another command. In response, the bot responds with a card (say Card2)  and a couple of action buttons. I have saved this conversation id and activity id also from the context.
At this point, the user may go and click an action button in Card1. I am hoping to identify Card 1 using the persisted activity id- but on inspecting the activity Id I see that its 
different from the value I persisted. How do I correctly identify a Card1 to respond to its action items?

(In 1:1, the conversationId for Card1 and Card2 is the same)

Comment: Are you saying you're seeing the same `conversationId` for every 1:1 conversation regardless of the user?

Comment: @Marc -I have updated my problelm statement

Comment: Are you saying that you prompt card 1 and then card 2, and in this time user click the button in card 1 and you get wrong result? What's the relation to conversation id and 1:1? I don't quite understand, could you please provide your code and steps to help us reproduce your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each interaction between BOT and user is an activity. So, every activity will have a different ID, meaning each time a user or BOT sends a message it will have a different activity ID.

I would assume that both card1 and card2 have different values on their buttons, if not then use some different text to identify which card button was pressed.

The BOT doesn't know that there was a button press or the user just typed in a message. BOT would treat each message separately unless there is a formflow or promptdialog.

Buttons have multiple fields such as Title or Value. You can use different value for each card. That way you would be able to identify which card it was that was clicked as the value of a button is sent back to the BOT.